# How to ignore certain strings when creating unique list of words in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula, regex

In Google Sheets, I am using the formula to create a unique list of words:

```
=unique(transpose(split(ArrayFormula(concatenate(B2:E"+")),"+")))
```

But I want to filter out certain strings.

My unique list looks like so:

```
On the road
Eggs
Bacon
Bread
Hashbrowns
Spreads
Baked Beans
Coffee
Avocado
Pub Roast
Sandwhich meet
Lettuce
Tomato
mustard
mayo
Tom to suss
James to suss
Crisps
Cheese
Crackers
Muslie Bars
```

I want to filter out strings like `Tom to suss`, `James to suss`, `On the road`, etc.

Comment: This question just has been bumped up by Community User. It already has an answer but it hasn't any comment from you and it's not accepted yet. What do you think of the current answer? Was it helpful?

Answer (score 0):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(UNIQUE(REGEXREPLACE(A1:A, 
 "Tom to suss|James to suss|On the road", "")), 
 "where Col1 is not null"))
```

[image: 0]

---

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(UNIQUE(REGEXREPLACE(A1:A, 
 "Tom to suss|James to suss|On the road", "")), 
 "where Col1 is not null")))
```

[image: 0]